# bibtex to html with pybtex, python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, bibtex

I want to take a file of one or more bibtex entries and output it as an html-formatted string.  The specific style is not so important, but let's just say APA. Basically, I want the functionality of [bibtex2html](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) but with a Python API since I'm working in Django. A few people have asked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038703/converting-bibtex-files-to-html-with-python-maybe-pybtex) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909919/using-pybtex-to-convert-from-bibtex-to-formatted-html-bibliography-in-e-g-harva).  I also found someone who provided a possible solution [here](https://www1.unipa.it/paolo.monella/pybtex/index.html).

The first issue I'm having is pretty basic, which is that I can't even get the above solutions to run.  I keep getting errors similar to `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybtex.database'; 'pybtex' is not a package`.  I definitely have pybtex installed and can make basic API calls in the shell no problem, but whenever I try to import pybtex.database.whatever or pybtex.plugin I keep getting `ModuleNotFound` errors.  Is it maybe a python 2 vs python 3 thing? I'm using the latter.

The second issue is that I'm having trouble understanding the pybtex python API [documentation](https://docs.pybtex.org/api/formatting.html#python-api).  Specifically, from what I can tell it looks like the `format_from_string` and `format_from_file` calls are designed specifically for what I want to do, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  Specifically, when I do

```
pybtex.format_from_file('foo.bib',style='html')
```

I get `pybtex.plugin.PluginNotFound: plugin pybtex.style.formatting.html not found`.  I think I'm just not understanding how the call is supposed to work, and I can't find any examples of how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function I wrote for a similar use case--incorporating bibliographies into a website generated by Pelican.

```
from pybtex.plugin import find_plugin
from pybtex.database import parse_string
APA = find_plugin('pybtex.style.formatting', 'apa')()
HTML = find_plugin('pybtex.backends', 'html')()

def bib2html(bibliography, exclude_fields=None):
    exclude_fields = exclude_fields or []
    if exclude_fields:
        bibliography = parse_string(bibliography.to_string('bibtex'), 'bibtex')
        for entry in bibliography.entries.values():
            for ef in exclude_fields:
                if ef in entry.fields.__dict__['_dict']:
                    del entry.fields.__dict__['_dict'][ef]
    formattedBib = APA.format_bibliography(bibliography)
    return "<br>".join(entry.text.render(HTML) for entry in formattedBib)
```

Make sure you've installed the following:

```
pybtex==0.22.2
pybtex-apa-style==1.3
```

Comment: Your script works very nicely. exclude_fields seems to be requiring a list variable - and it is indeed very handy to feed a list of "unwanted" keys to that def. It is a very fast and effective way of controlling the output style of a bibliography to HTML, without the need of modifying the style, per se, in some cases.

Comment: By the way, to get a numbered list in HTML, the following worked at least for me. Suppose your bibliography variable is called _data_.

`newdata = bib2html(data)` 
`newdata = newdata.replace("<br>","</li><li>")` 
`newdata = '<ol><li>' + newdata + '</li></ol>'`